# How to create (or not) class instance methods at construction time based on inputs?

Tags: perl, class

How would I create my class such that some methods will exist in the instance only if certain values were passed to the constructor?

Perhaps a more generic way of asking is:  How can I add a method to an existing class instance?

Comment: How about using  [`AUTOLOAD`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading)

Comment: I'm not seeing any way to do that with Autoload.  It doesn't seem to have access to the instance internals, which I need in order to know if a given method should be available or not.

Comment: THE `@_`passed to AUTOLOAD is the same as that that would be passed to the method so you can use `$self` like a method

Comment: I see.  I think I still need more details on how this would work.  Especially with the universal "can" method.

Comment: I can't believe noone has said this yet, but you're trying to implement a poor design, i.e. you're doing it wrong! You should provide more info and ask for a proper design instead.

Comment: As ikegami says, this is a *bad idea*. As well as the difficulty of implementing different methods dependent on context, you have the problem of the calling code having to discover somehow what methods it's allowed to call. If you explain the problem you're trying to solve this way I'm sure we can come up with a better technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach an anonymous sub to an object based on flags:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
package Object;
sub new {
   my $class = shift;
   my $self = bless {}, $class;
   my %args = @_; 
   if ($args{method}) {
       $self->{method} = sub { print "hello\n" }
   }   
   return $self;
}

sub method {
    my $self = shift;
    if (not defined $self->{method}) {
        warn "Not bound\n";
        return;
    }   
    $self->{method}->();
}
1;
```

to use:

```
use Object;
my $obj1 = Object->new(method=>1);
$obj1->method();
my $obj2 = Object->new();
$obj2->method();
```

You can extend this to a number of methods through the same interface.

Comment: In most cases, a flag would be simpler

Answer (score 2):

You can use Moose to apply a role at runtime.

```
package My::Class;
use Moose;

has foo => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'ro', required => 1 );

sub BUILD {
  my $self = shift;

  if ($self->foo eq 'bar') {
    My::Class::Role->meta->apply($self);
  }  
}

no Moose;

package My::Class::Role;
use Moose::Role;

sub frobnicate {
  my $self = shift;

  print "Frobnicated!\n";
}

no Moose;

my $something = My::Class->new( foo => 'bar' );
print $something, "\n";
$something->frobnicate;
my $something_else = My::Class->new( foo => 'baz' );
print $something_else, "\n";
$something_else->frobnicate;
```

Gives:

```
Moose::Meta::Class::__ANON__::SERIAL::1=HASH(0x2fd5a10)
Frobnicated!
My::Class=HASH(0x2fd2c08)
Can't locate object method "frobnicate" via package "My::Class" at testmoose.pl line 32.
```

Answer (score 1):

use `AUTOLOAD` to define the function. As a example method foo is called if `$self->{foo} exists`

```
sub AUTOLOAD {
    my $methodname = $AUTOLOAD;
    if ($methodname eq "foo" && exists($_[0]->{foo})){
          goto &fooimplementationsub;
    }
    return;
}
```

An alternative technique is to use globs to define a new method at runtime

```
*PACKAGE::method = sub { 
    #code here
};
```

This has the disadvantage that the method is now visible to all instances of the class so is not quite what you want.

A third and possibly more risky/inefficient method is to use string eval

```
eval <<EOF
sub foo { 
    #code here
};
EOF
```

Again this has the disadvantage that the method is now visible to all instances of the class so is not quite what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Methods are just subroutines in a package, and a package is just a hash holding typeglobs. And hashes can be modified at runtime.

So you could, in theory, add or remove methods given values in a constructor.

```
package WeirdClass;

sub new {
  my ($class, $name, $code) = @_;
  if ($name) {
    no strict;
    *{__PACKAGE__ . "::$name"} = $code;
  }
  bless {} => $class;
}
```

And then use it like:

```
my $object = WeirdClass->new(foo => sub {say "foo"});
$object->foo(); # prints "foo\n";
```

However, this method is available for all objects of that class:

```
my $another_object = WeirdClass->new();
$another_object->foo; # works too.
```

---

Using autoload, one can mock arbitrary methods:

```
package BetterClass;

sub new {
  my ($class, %args) = @_;
  bless \%args => $class;
}

# destructor will be called at cleanup, catch with empty implementation
sub DESTROY {}; 

sub AUTOLOAD {
  my $self = shift;
  (my $method = our $AUTOLOAD) =~ s/.*://; #  $AUTOLOAD is like "BetterClass::foo"

  # check if method is allowed
  die "forbidden method $method" unless $self->{can}{$method};

  # mock implementations
  given ($method) {
    say "foo" when "foo";
    say "bar" when "bar";
    when ("add") {
      my ($x, $y) = @_;
      return $x + $y;
    }
    default { die "unknown method $method" }
  }
}
```

Then:

```
my $o = BetterClass->new(can => { foo => 1, bar => 0});
$o->foo;
my $p = BetterClass->new(can => {bar => 1, add => 1});
$p->bar;
say $p->add(5, 6);
```

Of course, these techniques can be combined freely.

---

#### Edit: `can()`

To make the `AUTOLOAD` work with can, the protected methods should be moved into a data structure:

```
my %methods;
BEGIN {
  %methods = (
    foo => sub {say "foo"},
    bar => sub {say "bar"},
    add => sub {
      my ($self, $x, $y) = @_;
      $x + $y;
    },
  );
}
```

Then override the `can` method:

```
# save a reference to the origional `can` before we override
my $orig_can;
BEGIN{ $orig_can = __PACKAGE__->can("can") }

sub can {
  my ($self, $meth) = @_;

  # check if we have a special method
  my $code = $methods{$meth} if ref $self and $self->{can}{$meth};
  return $code if $code;

  # check if we have a normal method
  return $self->$orig_can($meth);
}
```

And `AUTOLOAD` would change to

```
my ($self) = @_; # do not `shift`
(my $method = our $AUTOLOAD) =~ s/.*://;
my $code = $self->can($method) or die "unknown method $method";
goto &$code; # special goto. This is a AUTOLOAD idiom, and avoids extra call stack frames
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't do too much magic. I've gotten away from `AUTOLOAD` because it causes maintenance issues where mysterious methods suddenly appear and disappear.

One way to handle what you want is to define all the methods you need, and if a particular object is of the wrong type, simply cause that method to *croak*:

```
sub Foo {
    my $self       = shift;
    my $parameter  = shift;

    if ( $self->Class_type ne "Foo" ) {
        croak qq(Invalid method 'Foo' on object @{[ref $self]});
    }
    print "here be dragons\";
    return "Method 'Foo' successfully called";
}
```

The above will not allow method `Foo` to be called unless the *class type* is `Foo`.

If your objects won't change (or you don't want them to change) once an object is created, you can define that object as a sub-class.

Before you *bless* a newly created object, check that special value and decide whether or not you need to create a specific sub-class instead.

```
package My_class;

sub new {
    my $class      = shift;
    my $class_type = shift;

    my $self = shift;

   if ( $class_type eq "Foo" ) {
      bless $self, "My_class::Foo";
   }
   else {
     bless $self, $class;
   }

package My_class::Foo;
use base qw(My_class);

sub Foo {
    my $self = shift;
    return "Foo Method successfully called!";
}
```

Notice that my class `My_class::Foo` is a sub-class of `My_class` via the `use base` pragma. That means all methods for `My_class` are valid with objects of `My_class::Foo`. However, only objects of `My_class::Foo` can call the `Foo` method.

When I create my object (via the `new` subroutine), I look at the `$class_type` parameter. If it's a type `Foo`, I `bless` the class as `My_class::Foo`.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/qazwart/Autoconfig/blob/master/autoconfig.pl) where I use sub-classes to do what you want.

Every object is a class type of `Question`. You can see my constructor on line 1129. I pass in a question type as one of the parameters to my constructor.

In line 1174 to 1176, I create my object, but then append the question type to the class, and then bless the question as that sub-class type. All of my subclasses are a type `Question` (see my `use base qw(Question);` below each `package` declaration. However, only questions of sub-class `Question::Date` and `Question::Regex` have a method `Format`. And, only objects of type `Question::Words` have a method `Force`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers so far given actually handle the question actually asked.

Adding methods to an *instance* in Perl is not directly supported. Object instances are always instances of some class, and that class is the thing that actually has methods. You cannot add a method to a single instance of a class, without making that method also available on every other instance of the same class.

For your problem you have two basic solutions:

1. Provide the methods always, but test a flag to see whether the method should apply to the given instance or not. This is by far the simplest.
2. Bless each object into subclasses depending on the flags. Subclass the main class to provide those methods as appropriate.

If you truely want to add methods on individual instances, then what you'll have to do is arrange that every instance is a single instance of a newly-derived class for every object. This gets harder to arrange for, doubly-so if you want to avoid leaking memory and cleaning up the classes once the objects are `DESTROY`ed. This would however allow truely per-instance methods.

Since it is highly unlikely you'll truely need this third option it is far better to go with one of the first.

Comment: Hi, sorry for off-topic, but could you visit http://stackoverflow.com/q/16999208/757808 and look at my question regardin libvterm?